# Calculate a specific moving average using sql query

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql

Consider that I have a table with one column "A" and I would like to create another column called "B" such that

`B[i] = 0.2*A[i] + 0.8*B[i-1]`

where `B[0]=0`.

My problem is that I cannot use the `OVER()` function because I want to use the values in B while I am trying to construct B. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you provide an example with data and expected results?

Comment: Thank you for your consideration. Let "A" be [1, 2, 3, 0]:
B[0] = 0.2*1 + 0.8*0 = 0.2,  
B[1] = 0.2*2 + 0.8*0.2 = 2,  
B[2] = 0.2*3 + 0.8*2 = 2.2,  
B[3] = 0.2*0 + 0.8*2.2 = 1.76

Comment: I'm not really understanding that in SQL terms...

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complex mathematical exercise.  You want to accumulate exponentially decreasing amounts from previous rows.

It is a little confusing because the amount going in on each row is 20%, but that is just a factor in the formula.

In any case, this seems to do what you want:

```
select t.*,
       sum(power(0.8, -n) * a * 0.2) over (order by id) / power(0.8, -n)
from (select t.8,
             row_number() over (order by id) - 1 as n
      from t
     ) x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=421bbb31ef5846be49f787ce103bebd1) is a db<>fiddle using Postgres.